# Reference functions in an R package by package+function name

Tags: r, devtools

I'm working on an automation tool which receives R packages-under-development at a known folder (e.g. `/src`) and wants to run certain functions from the package within a broader context: For example running function `do_a_thing()`.

One problem is that, although the package can be reliably loaded e.g. with `devtools::load_all("src")`, I don't know what package name the author might have put in the `Package` field of the `DESCRIPTION` file.

This means I can't just call `src::do_a_thing()`, because the actual form might be e.g. `MyWeirdPackageName::do_a_thing()`.

I know the `desc` package supports looking up this package name:

```
library(desc)
desc <- description$new("src")
desc$get("Package")

# > Package: 'MyWeirdPackageName'
```

...and also that `exists` can check for existence of the target function in the package:

```
exists("do_a_thing", where=paste("package", desc$get("Package"), sep=":"), mode="function")

# > TRUE
```

...But how can I actually *call* this function given that I know (at runtime, as a character vector) its fully qualified name is `MyWeirdPackageName::do_a_thing`?

Vanilla `get` doesn't seem to be able to handle the namespace aspect either by accepting a `where` argument or taking a fully-qualified name as input:

```
testfn <- get(paste(desc$get("Package"), "::do_a_thing", sep=''), mode="function")

# > Error in get(paste(desc$get("Package"), "::do_a_thing", sep = ""), mode = "function"): object
#   'MyWeirdPackageName::do_a_thing' of mode 'function' was not found
```

How can I explicitly invoke the `do_a_thing` function from *this* package, given that I know it exists and the name of the package it lives in?

Comment: `getFunction("data.table", where = eval(bquote(asNamespace(.(packagename)))))`?

Comment: `packagename <- as.name(packagename); eval(bquote(\`::\`(.(packagename), do_a_thing)))`?

Comment: Thanks @Roland - The use of `getFunction` does seem a little nicer / more constrained than `eval` and I see that it works with `where` as I'd expect... Although are there reasons for going with the `eval/bquote` combo over e.g. stitching char vectors together with `paste`?

Comment: `parse` is slow and inefficient and a strong security risk. If that is not an issue, you can of course use it. However, it can result in very cryptic error messages if the code being parsed throws an error. That hurts mantainability.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `eval(parse(text="code here"))` trick.
For example,

```r
mean(c(1,2,3,4))
#[1] 2.5

# is equivalent to

eval(parse(text="mean(c(1,2,3,4))"))
#[1] 2.5
```

So in your case, this would work.

```r
eval(parse(text="MyWeirdPackageName::do_a_thing"))
```

If you can get your package name as string (I think you are already good with that), then you can substitute that like:

```r
packagename <- "???"
eval(parse(text=paste0(packagename, "::do_a_thing")))
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes a solution like that does seem to work for what I'm after - although as Roland pointed out in comment above, I guess using `getFunction("do_a_thing", where="package::MyWeirdPackageName")` might be a bit better than open-ended `eval`?